# Django 1.6 queryset

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, django-queryset

I have the following query and I am trying to set it in the Django 1.6 ORM

```
SELECT * FROM pharol.product
where name like "%PARACETAMOL%" or principe_active like "%PARACETAMOL%"
order by case when name like 'PARACETAMOL%' then 0 else 1 end, name
```

From the query I have already set the query but it is subtracting `order by case when name like 'PARACETAMOL%' then 0 else 1 end, name`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your Django models.

Comment: Show us also your query. Your question has an answer for 1.6 fortunately, (I recommend however to think about upgrade, because version 1.6 is now unsupported. I do it usually before adding new features to an old project. Django has no online documentation for 1.6 yet.)